# PHP First Letter Uppercase of Each Word In Output

Tags: php, capitalization

I am wanting the output to have the First Letter Of Each Word uppercase. Here is my code.

```
function random_title () 
{ 
    $quotes1 = file ("wp-content/plugins/includes/classes/quotes.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $quotes1 = ucwords($quotes1);
    $num = rand (0, intval (count ($quotes1) / 3)) * 3;
    return $quotes1[$num];
}
```

Usage is:

```
random_title()
```

This part is not working, what am I doing wrong? I get no output when I put this in, but if I take it out I do get my titles but they are lowercase as they are in the text file.

```
    $quotes1 = ucwords($quotes1);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you need to use ucfirst to make first letter in capitals. and you need to use it at the time of returning i think

Comment: based on `return $quotes1[$num];`, `$quotes1` is an array, but `ucwords()` is to be used on a string - [`string ucwords ( string $str )
`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php). You could do `return ucwords($quotes1[$num]);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ucwords`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) works on a single string, not an array. Just apply it **after** selecting a random title:

```
function random_title () 
{ 
    $quotes1 = file ("wp-content/plugins/includes/classes/quotes.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $num = rand (0, intval (count ($quotes1) / 3)) * 3;
    return ucwords($quotes1[$num]); # Here!
}
```

Comment: but it should upeercase all the letters ? isn't it?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh `ucwords` capitalizes the first character in every word. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Yes, the above code outputs as: This Is Your Output